# Lookup table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm doing my first work in PHP/MySQL & I need help. I have one master table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `m4l_movies` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `Rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Genre` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `Actors` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

that receives input for a form which has values from a these lookup tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `m4l_actors` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Actor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=232 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `m4l_genre` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Genre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=202 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `m4l_movierating` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Movie_Rating` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

& I've created a View:

```sql
SELECT m4l_movies.ID AS ID,
  m4l_movies.Title AS Title,
  m4l_movierating.Movie_Rating AS Rating,
  m4l_movies.Actors AS Actors,
  m4l_movies.Genre AS Genre
FROM m4l_movies
  JOIN m4l_movierating ON m4l_movierating.ID = m4l_movies.Rating
  INNER JOIN m4l_genre ON m4l_movies.Genre = m4l_genre.ID
  INNER JOIN m4l_actors ON m4l_movies.Actors = m4l_actors.ID
ORDER BY m4l_movies.Title
```

Here is the out put I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------|
  ID      Title       Rating    Actor         Genre             |
  10      Summer      G         (10,15,25)    (45,115,123)      |
   1      About You   G-1       (63,163,405)  (3,16,51)         |
   5      Dog Years   P         (45,65,95)    (98,163,357)      |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Firstly this view should return more than 200 records. Secondly, I need to know how to either create a *lookup* or some other method to convert the NAME & GENRE back to their corresponding text values. Some how the RATING value is doing it right but I can't get NAME  or GENRE to do it correctly. I'm sure it has to do with either the way I've joined the tables but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Will someone PLEASE help me.

Ok trying to follow along with suggesting made by Phil I've removed actors, genre from movies tale & created movies_genre & movies_actors

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `m4l_movies`;
CREATE TABLE `m4l_movies` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Year` float NOT NULL,
  `Review` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Storyline` longtext NOT NULL,
  `Director` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


 CREATE TABLE `m4l_movie_actor` (
    movie_id INT(11),
    actor_id INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES m4l_movies (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES m4l_actors (ID)
 );


CREATE TABLE `m4l_movie_genre` (
    movie_id INT(11),
    genre_id INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, genre_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES m4l_movies (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES m4l_genre (ID)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m4l_genre;
CREATE TABLE m4l_genre (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  Genre varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m4l_actors;
CREATE TABLE m4l_actors (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  Actor varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but when I try to create the movie_actor OR movie_genre I get

> 09:29:45
>   CREATE TABLE `m4l_movie_actor` (movie_id INT(11), actor_id INT(11),
>   PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
>   FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES m4l_movies (ID),
>    FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES m4l_actors (ID) )
>   Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   0.000 sec
>
> 09:40:56 CREATE TABLE `m4l_movie_genre` (movie_id INT(11),genre_id INT(11),
>   PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, genre_id),
>   FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES m4l_movies (ID),
>   FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES m4l_genre (ID) )
>   Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   0.016 sec

From what I can gather this only occurs when you have data types mismatch, but I THINK I have all INT data types so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Never (and I mean **never**) store comma separated foreign keys in a single field. Use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) instead.

Comment: Phil if you could explain what & how to do that I'm all for it...I just trying to get this thing to work.

Comment: Yes I looked at it & was just as much as I am now. Creating a "junction table" sound nice, but I'm using a program called PHPMaker to create the actual pages for input / edit / view of the DB so how do I get the data from the form to this table?

Comment: http://forums.hkvstore.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=27547

Comment: @Phil, Thank you so much your advice last nite(this morning) was invaluable...it help a LOT. So THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I think you need to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM if you want real foreign keys. You may also need to make the junction table *id* columns `NOT NULL` so they exactly match the target keys

Comment: Yes I saw that too thanks, got another question I can't add or edit records through the ViewList. Is there a way to create a single interface to add or edit record so I don't have to add/edit each table separately?

Answer (score 5):

You appear to have made the classic blunder of storing relational data in an un-relatable way.

You should be using [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) instead of comma separated values. For example...

```
CREATE TABLE `m4l_movies` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `Rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
    -- removed Actors and Genre
    `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `m4l_movie_actor` (
    movie_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    actor_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES m4l_movies (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES m4l_actors (ID)
);

-- repeat for genres
```

You can then join on the junction table and on to the `Actors` / `Genres` tables, eg

```
SELECT ... m4l_actors.Actor ...
FROM m4l_movies
INNER JOIN m4l_movie_actor ON m4l_movies.ID = m4l_movie_actor.movie_id
INNER JOIN m4l_actors ON m4l_movie_actor.actor_id = m4l_actors.ID
```

If you want the result in a comma separated list, look into [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)